# Microsoft Web API 2 AuthenticationSchemes

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, windows-authentication, bearer-token, .net-4.8

we have a app with two different Authentecations.
Only One Controller and one get call Use Windows Authentication.

All other Controller uses JWT Token with Owin.

In net 8.0 I can use [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Negotiate")] or [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer")] but in old full framework this still not exists. Is there something simmelar?

the actual problem is that the one controler with Windows Authentication is still not working and http context is empty.

thank you

Comment: Have you checked Policy Based authentication? insteas of schemes?